# 2D Vector resize runtime error

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

I'm having a problem resizing my two dimensional vectors.

```
std::vector<std::vector<NavigationNode>> *nodes;
nodes->resize(sizex);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizex ;i++)
    nodes[i].resize(sizey);
```

It works as intended when `i` is `0`, but crashes when `i` is `1`.

Do you know why?

Comment: Also: care to show the definition of `nodes`?  And post the error message?

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<NavigationNode>> *nodes;

Comment: You will need to post a complete example (please see http://sscce.org).

Comment: error is a generic runtime error.

Comment: There is no such thing as a generic runtime error.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in program.exe.

Comment: nodes[1].size() is 70740637. it says size is higher than wanted size and tries to call erase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the type of `nodes` to be a pointer to a vector of vectors. Presuming that this pointer has been initialized to correctly allocated memory, `nodes[i]` is not calling operator[] on the outer vector, it's accessing the memory `nodes` points to as if it is a contiguous array. It is equivalent to `*(nodes+i)`.

In this case, more correct syntax would be `(*nodes)[i]`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<NavigationNode>> *nodes;
nodes->resize(sizex);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizex ;i++)
    (*nodes)[i].resize(sizey); //line changed
```

Comment: initilized it like this:
nodes = new std::vector<std::vector<NavigationNode>>;
(*nodes)[i] does not compile

Comment: error was; one of the classes i wrote did not have a default constructor. using nodes[i] was just masking it. replacing it with (*node)[i] allowed me to track it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a pointer to vector. Well, don't.

```
std::vector<std::vector<NavigationNode>> nodes(
    sizex, std::vector<NavigationNode>(sizey)
);
```

Even better, use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

```
boost::multi_array<NavigationNode, 2> nodes(boost::extents[sizex][sizey]);
```

Comment: why does pointer cause error? i really need the pointer to create vector in constructor.
is multiarray faster than std::vector?

Comment: @mikbal: Why do you *need* the pointer? Speed is not important, you optimise when you've got something to profile.

Comment: nodes is a member of pathfinder class. it's called a lot by other classes. also initialized later by using values sizex and sizey (which are supplied by levelloader class) . sizex and sizey is only known when random level is constructed.

Comment: i dont understand :S where will i initialize nodes? i cant do it in constructor. i cant think of anything. i cant do something like this &nodes = new std::vector<.... am i?